# ionic angular gesture pinch crashing ios

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hammer.js

I'm trying to listen for a pinch element on `#touchpad` within my app.

I've tried the following two methods, both of which work in the browser (chrome and safari) but when loaded on iOS they break the rest of the js from running.

```
     ionic.onGesture("pinch", function(e){ 
       socket.emit("pinch", { scale: e.gesture.scale })
     }, $document[0].querySelector("#touchpad") )
```

`

```
      touchpad = angular.element(document.getElementById("touchpad"));
       $ionicGesture.on('pinch', function(e){ 
         socket.emit("pinch", { scale: e.gesture.scale } );
       }, touchpad);
```

Has anybody had experience with pinch gesture on iOS for ionic?

Here is the seemingly irrelevant console error (captured through safari/ios emulator)

`[Error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.buttons.length')
    (anonymous function) (ionic.bundle.js, line 20434)
    (anonymous function) (ionic.bundle.js, line 17384)
    $broadcast (ionic.bundle.js, line 23549)
    (anonymous function) (socket.min.js, line 7)
    (anonymous function) (socket.min.js, line 7)
    (anonymous function) (ionic.bundle.js, line 25050)
    completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js, line 13732)
    (anonymous function) (ionic.bundle.js, line 14112)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was adding the listener onto the #touchpad element before it had been rendered on screen.

Only iOS seemed to have a problem with this.